# Aling UIView to a UIToolbar using autolayout

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, autolayout

I trying to align an UIView to the bottom of a container view(UIScroolView) and above a tool bar.
It works perfectly when design to the iphone 3.5 display but when a change my layout to the 4.0 display, my view doesn't get alined to the bottom instead it stays in the same position with a gap from the UIToolbar.

[image: iPhone 3.5 display]

[image: iPhone 4.0 display]

I checked and i realized the i have a constraint Vertical Space with a constant and i think thats why my view always stays in the same place, the problem is i can't get rid of this constraint, i'd like to know if someone could help me with this one.

[image: Constraint]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a height constraint to the toolbar. If you have that and a zero length vertical spacing constraint between the toolbar and scroll view, you should be able to delete that constraint to the top of the super view.